# "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" on EmployeeExperience.LearningProviders.GetAsync()

Tags: azure, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

I need to get (and eventually create) the LearningProvider(s) in a certain Azure Tenant.
The creation is done by this call in C#:

```
   var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
   {
       AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
   };
   var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tid, AppClientId, AppClientSecret, jwt, options);
   var client = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
   var learningProviders = await client.EmployeeExperience.LearningProviders.GetAsync();
```

Where:

- **tid**: Logged user Tenant ID
- **AppClientId/Secret**: The registered App Id/Secret
- **jwt**: The logget user JWT token

The error which returns when I try to get the LearningProviders is:

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.MainError 
Code: forbidden 
Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I have the following permissions in the register app:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error *"Forbidden*" usually occurs if the signed-in user does not have required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran your code in my environment with same permissions:

[image]

To work with learning providers, logged in user need either *Global Admin* or *Knowledge Admin* role, along with `LearningProvider.ReadWrite` permission of **Delegated** type.

In my case, I assigned ***Knowledge Administrator*** role to the logged in user like this:

[image]

When I ran the code again now after assigning above role, I got the **response** successfully with learning provider details like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var tid = "xxxxxxx";
var AppClientId = "xxxxxxx";
var AppClientSecret = "xxxxxxx";

var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var jwt = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(
    tid, AppClientId, AppClientSecret, jwt, options);

var client = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
try
{
    var learningProviders = await client.EmployeeExperience.LearningProviders.GetAsync();
    foreach (var provider in learningProviders.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Learning Provider ID: {provider.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Learning Provider Name: {provider.DisplayName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Login Web Url: {provider.LoginWebUrl}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }       
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {odataError.Error.Message}");
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Permissions required to manage learningProvider - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/employeeexperience-post-learningproviders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Yes it works, these calls MUST be executed by a user with Knowledge Administrator role, thank you!